# Stop at word in regex

Tags: c#, regex

I know that I can do the following [^h] to get all matches accept the ones with a 'h'.
How would I do this with an entire word, like ^(word)

Comment: please explain your question properly

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to match a string that *is not identical to* `foo`:

```
^(?!foo).*$
```

If you want to match a string that *does not contain* `foo`:

```
^(?!.*foo).*$
```

If you want to match a string that does not contain `foo` *as a complete word*:

```
^(?!.*\bfoo\b).*$
```

If you want to match a string *until `foo` appears* and stop the match before `foo`:

```
^(?:(?!foo).)*
```

These solutions do not handle newlines in the string, so you might have to set the corresponding regex options like `RegexOptions.Singleline` in .NET if that's a problem.

`(?!foo)` is a [zero-width negative lookahead expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), meaning that it asserts that it is not possible ("negative") to match `foo` following the current position in the string ("look *ahead*"), while not consuming any characters in the match attempt ("zero-width").

Answer (score 3):

There’s really no good way to do this with regular expressions. The nearest you can get is to use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that will find the regular expression *only if* it’s not followed by the string in the negative lookahead …:

```
foo(?!word)
```

Will only find `foo` not followed by `word`.

The same exists for looking behind (instead ahead):

```
(?<!word)foo
```

Will only find `foo` if it’s not preceded by `word`.